# Conditional parse checkout with svn:external in TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am currently setting up a complex project in an SVN repo, and I have been facing some issues in terms of some of the requirements for the operation of the repo.

My repository is composed of modules, which contain identical folder structures. Let's say *module A* contains the following folder structure:

- *folder1*
- *folder2*
- *folder3*

Given some other requirements for the project organisation, the modules are put together into a meaningful configuration (let's call it *config*) by means of externals to these modules, that live in the same repository. This means that, for instance, a certain configuration *config A* could have 2 modules:

1. *config A*

   - *module A*

     - *folder1*
     - *folder2*
     - *folder3*
   - *module B*

     - *folder1*
     - *folder2*
     - *folder3*

In order to separate the usage of the modules into users, I created a structure with *tiers*, in which upon checkout, if *tier 1* was selected, only the *folder1* of a module would be checked out, or if *tier 2* was selected, *folder1* and *folder2* of a module would be checked out. So, for instance, *config A*, checked out under *tier 2*, would have the following structure:

1. *config A*

   - *module A*

     - *folder1*
     - *folder2*
   - *module B*

     - *folder1*
     - *folder2*

I have done a test with a python script that contains the paths to the *modules*, and does a partial checkout according to the *tier* it receives, but by doing that, my local structure becomes a set of individual checkouts. In this case, I lose some of the benefits externals offer, namingly detecting changes in the externals and being able to swap the external address.

I wonder if there is a more integrated way in svn, preferably in TortoiseSVN, in which we can set a variable, corresponding to the desired tier, such that all the externals are checked out partially, in which only the folders corresponding to the tier are checked out.

I hope the description of the problem is clear. I've been trying to figure out a solution for a long time, but with no success! Thank you.

Comment: Why not having a separate folder for every tier, and then assign appropriate externals to each of those folders? BTW, I don't think there is a way to control the checkout. Once you give the URL to the SVN client all you can do is manually fiddle with sparse checkouts.

Comment: You would have to have both separate config and module folders. All files that are directly in those folders would have to be duplicated, but such is life.